# c# Register custom dll as processor to Printer++ Config file

Tags: c#, dll, printing, processor

I am trying to create a custom printer driver to generate images. For this, I have installed Printer++ which converts print files to postscripts. To convert  postscript file to image, I am using ghostscript. Independently both the processes are running fine and I am able to achieve what is required.

But, I need a custom process to generate images in one go. I followed through the [Printer++ tutorial](http://www.printerplusplus.com/Tutorial) but it didn't work. 
This is what I have done:

1. I installed Printer++ and gave the name of the printer driver as- Septane.
2. In Visual Studio, I created a project- Test.

And the following code in Processor.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using PrinterPlusPlusSDK;
namespace Test
{
    public class Processor : PrinterPlusPlusSDK.IProcessor
    {
        public PrinterPlusPlusSDK.ProcessResult Process(string key, string psFilename)
        {
             //Convert PS to Png
             psFilename = "b.ps";
             MessageBox.Show("Rahul");
             ConvertPsToTxt(psFilename);
        }
        public static string ConvertPsToTxt(string psFilename, string txtFilename)
        {
            var retVal = string.Empty;
            var errorMessage = string.Empty;
            var command = "C:\\PrinterPlusPlus\\gs\\gswin64.exe";
            var args = string.Format("-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dFirstPage=1 -q -r300   -sDEVICE=png256 -sOutputFile=", psFilename, txtFilename);
            retVal = Shell.ExecuteShellCommand(command, args, ref errorMessage);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

This class inherits from `PrinterPlusPlusSDK.IProcessor` and implements the `PrinterPlusPlusSDK.ProcessResult` Process function. I have tested the standalone console project (without using PrinterPlusPlusSDK processor) and that converts ps to png successfully.

3. Now, as per the tutorial, the dll needs to be deployed to printer++ and registered as a processor. I copied Test.dll to Printer++ installation folder and added an entry to PrinterPlusPlus.exe.config file.

The config entry looks like:

```
<processors>
  <add key="Test" 
    value="Test.Processor, Septane, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</processors>
```

That's it. Now, when I print a file, it gives an error:

> Proccessor not found for: Septane

What am I doing wrong? 
If anyone has better idea for achieving the same, please let me know. Actually, mine is a commercial product so can't use CutePDF/VerPDf kind options.

**Edit:** I now know why I was getting error- Processor not found. I renamed my  printer to Test and the error disappeared. I have edited my code as well.

For testing, I have added a message box. I expected to get a popup once I give print command. But that is not the case. The ps file is getting generated without an error and that's it. I can't view pop-up message and there is no png converted file. Can someone please help me resolve this issue at least? It doesn't seem to be picking up the dll at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei for formatting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Remember The Printer name must be same as the you dll name

If your printer driver name is Septane. Then you must have to create a project name with "Septane". In that case project name "Test" will not work.